# "could not find driver" error for "new PDO()" command, PHP 7.0.25

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not able to use "new PDO()" as I keep getting this error message, "could not find driver."  I'm using hostgator, and have worked extensively with them, to no avail.

I've updated my PHP version to 7.0.25, checked the default php.ini settings (hostgator uses a cookie-cutter default php.ini file for all their customers... unless you create your own custom php.ini file, in which case the custom version overrides).  I've looked over my phpinfo() results, and everything looks good (unless I'm missing something).  I've included my script and snippets of my php.ini file settings and phpinfo() results.

PHP.ini file settings:

[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

phpinfo() results:

PDO drivers:  mysql, sqlite

Client API version:  5.6.41-84.1

Directive:  pdo_mysql.default_socket

Local value: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Master value:  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "ABC";
$pw = "123";
$dbName = "XYZ";
$dsn = 'msql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbName;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pw); // this is the line that the error refers to

$eml = $_POST['data'];
$newPassword = $_POST['data1'];
$cnewPassword = $_POST['data2'];
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = $eml") or die(mysql_error());
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            if($row > 0) {
                echo "GOOD";
            } else {
                echo "BAD";
            }; 

?>
```

I should get an echo "GOOD", but all I keep getting is the "could not find driver" error.  One important thing to note; I did notice that the PHP version that hostgator used to upgrade was a NON THREAD SAFETY version... hostgator uses APACHE servers, and I've learned that only the THREAD SAFE versions will work with APACHE servers.  This could be the issue, but not 100 percent sure.  Any input/advice would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a mysqli driver that you can use as well?

Comment: Did you notice that you chose "msql" not "mysql" in your dsn? I think this problem is just a typographical error.

Comment: Do you really have an mSql database, and not a MySQL database?

Comment: wow... yeah typo on my end, fixed the dsn command.  However, I'm still getting an error, this time it's "fatal error, uncaught PDO exception, access denied for user...".  My pw is accurate, I've double checked that with hostgator.  Any thoughts on this matter?  Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax error:

```php
// $dsn = 'msql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbName;<br>
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbName;<br>
```

(`msql` instead of `mysql`).